# Detecting server overload to limit mysql queries

Tags: php, c++, mysql, service, apache2

I'm programming c++ service which constantly every 1 second makes SELECT query with LIMIT 1 on mysql server, something computes and then makes INSERT and this in loop forever and ever.

I'd like to detect server overloading to make SELECTs with bigger LIMIT, for example LIMIT 10 and in greater inetrvals, like every 5 seconds or so. Not sure if my solution will lighten server overloads.

My problem is how to detect these overloads and I'm not sure what I mean by overload :) It could be anything, but my application is web application in php (chat) so overload could be detected on Apache2 side, or mysql side, or detecting how many users make how many inputs (chat messages) in time interval. I don't know :/

Thank you!

**EDIT:** Okay, I made an socket server from my C++ application and its really fast that way. Now I'm struggling with memory leaks, but that's another story.

So thank you **@brianbeuning** for helpful thoughts about my problem.

Comment: A polling design, like yours, is not usually good.  You want to find some way to make it event driven.  Reading from a socket, or reading an MSMQ queue is event driven.

Comment: @brianbeuning can you please navigate me to some tutorial about c++ socket server and php client communication?

Comment: A server socket will use socket(), bind(), listen(), and accept() to set up the socket for connections.  And select(), read(), and write() to handle requests.  The client will use socket(), connect(), write(), read(), and close().

Answer (score 1):

Better solve that forever and ever loop, its not good idea.

If that loop is really must, then use some caching technique.

For detecting "overload" (I would call it high MySQL CPU usage), try calling external commands supported by operating system.

For example if you use this on **Linux**, play with **ps** command.

---

**EDIT:**

I realized now that you are programming chatting server.
Using MySQL as middleman is NOT good idea.
Try solving this without using MySQL, and then if you need to save chat log, occasionally save it to MySQL (eg. every 10 seconds or so).

I bet it is CPU hog right now for just 20 intensive users.

Try to make direct client-to-client communication, without requiring server (use server only to establish communication between 2 clients).

Comment: loop is must, I must process and alayze all text real-time as soon as possible. Is there any module to apache? I run this process sometimes on linux and sometimes on windows too. Thank you

Comment: Even if it exists, I am not aware of it.

Comment: Try memcached. Skip the MySQL part.

Comment: Now I'm thinking about memcached.

Comment: Now I'm thinking about connecting C++ application with PHP application via Thrift. Its event driven approach as mentioned @brianbeuning above. But I'm struggling to find fully functional example working on windows :/

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to buffer the data in your app and use a connection pool of sorts to manage the load. Keep a rolling buffer of data that needs to be inserted and manage the 'limit' based on the size of the buffer.